# Removing header <frameset> in redirected sites

Tags: html, redirect, frameset

I am facing an issue with mobile version of my site. The site is hosted on a different domain.

I Tracked down the issue and saw that its being caused by the  being wrapped on top of my actual html code.

Here is a snippet:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Where are you</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="description" content="Letâ€™s your friends and family know about your where about.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Stay connected, Plan meetup, Unreachable friend, Share location, Share photos">
    </head>
    <frameset rows="100%">
        <frameset cols="100%">
            <frame src="http://wru.buttur.com" frameborder="0">
            #document
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

My website is getting loaded inside "#document".

Can i do some configuration on my domain to prevent this from happening.

Comment: where's your body tag?

Comment: my whole html is wrapped inside "#document". It has the actual html of my page. The above mentioned html is just wrapping the whole page html.

Comment: so http://wru.buttur.com is your site and the html above is a site that pulls your site into the frame, Is that correct ? you coould put js on top of your document to make sure it is the parent document. put this in the head of your page `<script>
if (window !== top) top.location = window.location;
</script>`

Comment: Hi Billy. Sorry was not clear earlier. My site is "minicode.co". Its hosted under "wru.buttur.com". And the above mentioned html is shown when i see view source of "minicode.co"

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I am responding because we had a similar problem where some outside entity managed a website, and we took over after it became broken.

It was a wordpress site and everything was being wrapped inside a frameset. We were baffled by the fact that direct browser requests to hosted javascript files would work fine, but within the page it would become wrapped in frames in the network response.
Even direct jQuery.getScript() calls from external sites would exhibit the scenario. Again, worked fine if typed into browser url bar.

Turns out there's something called DNS frame forwarding. 
Here's a topic that covers the scenario:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083391/godaddy-dns-forward-to-ip-adds-frames-to-html

Edit: 
Looks like a moderator removed that post. How strange!!  Too bad as well, that post had exactly the right answer with exactly the right description.
Well basically anyone coming across this, just research DNS frame forwarding. You'll find your answer there.

Terms for google:
website wrapped in frameset
javascript responds in frame
css in frame
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <